# How to delete a java working set in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Sorry for the very basic question, but I can't find on google how to delete a working set.

So how can I delete a java working set in eclipse 3.4? Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the project explorer view, there's a toolbar with a down arrow that will show a menu when you click it. Choose *Select Working Set...*, and in the dialog that follows you can remove working sets

Comment: it's slightly different in 3.4 but it did the job ;) Thanks

Comment: In Rational Application Developer at least, there's also Enterprise Explorer.

Comment: Its unbelievable I actually had to look how this is done instead of just right clicking or hitting "Del", thanks for the help